# Laplacian $\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial r})= \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial ^2 }{\partial r^2}(r \phi )$

Tags: spherical-coordinates

Does anyone have any intuition on remembering or very quickly deriving that

$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial r}) = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial ^2 }{\partial r^2}(r \phi )$$

holds for the Laplacian in spherical coordinates? Doing the IBP is too long and slow, maybe there is some obvious obvious physical reason for this simplification making it obvious and easy to remember?

**Edit:** In other words, is there a nice natural way to start with

$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial r})$$

and derive the other side of the equality intuitively, without remembering it beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to take a look at how the Laplacian is derived for any system of curvilinear coordinates:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates

Comment: I can derive the Laplacian in any orthogonal system in 10 seconds, the problem is that some problems in electrostatics use the above simplification - I can derive the L.H.S. immediately but I can't remember the R.H.S. & need to re-derive it by integration by parts which takes time - time I wont have in an exam :(

Comment: It seems to me that you are wasting more time in looking for a detour than you would use to learn the formula.

Answer (score 0):

based on integration by parts with compactly supported functions, assuming you know that $\nabla f  = \partial_r f u_r$:
$$
\int \phi {\rm div} g dV = -\int \nabla \phi \cdot g dV
= -\int \partial_r \phi  g_r dV 
\\
= -\int \partial_r \phi g_r 4\pi r^2 dr = -\int  \phi 
\partial_r(r^2 g_r) 4\pi dr
= -\int  \phi 
\frac{\partial_r(r^2 g_r)}{r^2} 4\pi r^2 dr
$$and then $$
\Delta f = 
{\rm div} \nabla f =
{\rm div} (\partial_r f_r e_r)=
 \frac{\partial_r(r^2 \partial_r f_r )}{r^2}$$

Comment: Apologies, but I don't see how this addresses the question?

Comment: this is a fast way to compute the expression of the laplacian